# "Not defined" error in closing python function

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following chunk of code whose syntax appears fine to me. I get "num is not defined" error when I run the function. num is clearly a parameter and I assume I have to include it in the closing tag.

```
def restrict(num, minNum, maxNum):
    """Your comments here"""
    if ((num >= minNum) and (num <= maxNum)):
        return num
    elif (num < minNum):
        return minNum
    elif (num > maxNum):
        return maxNum

restrict(num, minNum, maxNum)

print(restrict(-1, 0, 255))
print(restrict(100, 0, 255))
print(restrict(256, 0, 255))
```

Answer (score 0):

> restrict(num, minNum, maxNum)

You have no definition for `num` or `minNum` or `maxNum` in this call.

Notice that in the *traceback* you are told where the exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 10, in <module>
    restrict(num, minNum, maxNum)
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

See the source line indicating that the problem is on line 10 where the call is being made.

Here's an example of how you might fix this:

```
def restrict(num, minNum, maxNum):
    """Your comments here"""
    if ((num >= minNum) and (num <= maxNum)):
        return num
    elif (num < minNum):
        return minNum
    elif (num > maxNum):
        return maxNum

# Notice the changes on _this_ line.
restrict(5, -5, 10)

print(restrict(-1, 0, 255))
print(restrict(100, 0, 255))
print(restrict(256, 0, 255))
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have to define parameters. I thought parameters are simply representatives of whatever inputs you're processing through the function

Comment: You never set the value for num, minNum or maxNum before passing them to the restrict method

Comment: Sorry I totally have no idea what you're talking about. Could you provide me with an example please?

Comment: @AronTesfay, just remove that line and run the code. Maybe you'll understand.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I thought I always had to close a function.